# How to make multiple QGraphicsView's drag/move an image when the action is performed in any one of them

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4

I am making an interface to compare images on which some processing will be done. To be specific the first would be a color image, the second grayscale, the third has an edge filter applied and possibly more. It would be nice to be able to zoom and drag in any one of these images and have the others react the same way to compare them.

Right now I have three pairs of QGraphicsScene's and QGraphicsView's, each one of them containing a QPixmap of the appropriate image, color or grayscale etc. I managed to do the zooming part by attaching an event filter to all the QGraphicsView's and catching the mouse wheel scroll event and distributing it to all the others. This however is not as easily done with the image dragging because it is comprised of multiple events.

It is feeling very 'hacked together' and I would like to know if there is a better way to achieve this. This is the code of the event filter I currently have, which doesn't work for the dragging:

```
def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
    if obj == self.viewA.viewport() or obj == self.viewB.viewport() or obj == self.viewC.viewport():
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Wheel:
            # This function passes the event to all the QGraphicsView's
            self.wheelEvent(event)
            return True
        elif event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseMove:
            # This doesn't work but just to give an idea of what I'm trying to achieve
            self.viewA.mouseMoveEvent(event)
            self.viewB.mouseMoveEvent(event)
            self.viewC.mouseMoveEvent(event)

            return True

    return False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your problem stems from that fact that QGraphicsViews do nothing with a mouseMoveEvent, unless the mouse was clicked on them. (i.e. you click, drag, and then release, not just move your mouse over the view).

I would suggest handling the appropriate click and release events as well as the mouseMoveEvent inside of the eventFilter. You'll need to use a bool to hold whether or not a drag is happening that you care about.

A possible alternative, and I'm not sure if this one will work, is that instead of using the mouseMoveEvent, you may need to use the dragMoveEvent.

Comment: Thanks, forwarding the MouseMove, MouseButtonPress and MouseButtonRelease event to all the graphics views does the trick. A bool wasn't neccesary. I also checked for the dragging events but they do not fire in the graphicsview.